# PHP - get a page content with fsockopen (skype username check)?

Tags: php, validation, skype, fsockopen

I've only **fsockopen** on my server to use. I mean I can't use cURL or file_get_contents. I'm using **PHP** by the way

I want to have a skype user name validation, so I found this link from an other topic:

https://login.skype.com/json/validator?new_username=anyUserName

This page responses as valid or invalid username as JSON output:
**{"status":200,"status_text":"valid","data":{"markup":"","alternatives":false,"fieldDetails":""}}**

It says valid, so this username is not exist. I may parse this data to see whether it's correct.

**My question is, How can i get this https page content with fsockopen**, I can open the socket I try to read data but i failed too many times with many snippets that I got from forums. Because I've no idea about how to do it, even if you can't write the code please tell me or show me a way to do it?

Basicly, how to return the skype id status with fsockopen **in PHP**, I'll be glad to get comments, thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have openssl in your php, you should be able to prefix the hostname or ip with `'ssl://'` or `'tls://'` with a proper port number and php should handle the rest. So simply like this:

```
fsockopen('ssl://78.141.177.180', 443, $errno, $errstr);
```

and use the returned resource as usual.
I myself use the function bellow when no curl available (code salvaged from [php.net comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php#76899) and massaged a little). call it like

```
not_curl_get('login.skype.com/json/validator?new_username=foo', 'ssl://', 443)
```

The function itself:

```
function not_curl_get($url, $protocol = '', $port = 80, $options = array()) {
    $options = array_merge(array(
        'follow_location'      => true,
        'return_response_part' => 'body',
        'referer'              => false,
        'user_agent'           => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; hu; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)',
        'cookie_file'          => false,
        'request_type'         => 'get',
    ), $options);

    global $_NOT_CURL_GET_OLDHEADER;
    $url = str_replace("http://","",$url);
    if (preg_match("#/#","$url")){
        $page = $url;
        $url = @explode("/",$url);
        $url = $url[0];
        $page = str_replace($url,"",$page);
        if (!$page || $page == ""){
            $page = "/";
        }
        $ip = gethostbyname($url);
    }else{
        $ip = gethostbyname($url);
        $page = "/";
    }
    $open = fsockopen($protocol.$ip, $port, $errno, $errstr, 60);
    if ($options['request_type'] === 'post'){
        $send = "POST $page HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    }else{
        $send = "GET $page HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    }
    $send .= "Host: $url\r\n";
    if ($options['referer']){
        $send .= "Referer: ".$options['referer']."\r\n";
    }
    if ($options['cookie_file']){
        if (@file_exists($options['cookie_file'])){
            $cookie = urldecode(@file_get_contents($options['cookie_file']));
            if ($cookie){
                $send .= "Cookie: $cookie\r\n";
                $add = @fopen($options['cookie_file'],'w');
                fwrite($add,"");
                fclose($add);
            }
        }
    }
    $send .= "Accept-Language: en-us, en;q=0.50\r\n";
    if ($options['user_agent']){
        $send .= "User-Agent: ".$options['user_agent']."\r\n";
    }
    if ($options['request_type']){
        $send .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
        $send .= "Content-Length: " .strlen($options['request_type']) ."\r\n\r\n";
        $send .= $options['request_type'];
    }else{
        $send .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    }
    fputs($open, $send);
    $return = '';
    while (!feof($open)) {
        $return .= fgets($open, 4096);
    }
    fclose($open);
    $return = @explode("\r\n\r\n",$return,2);
    $header = $return[0];
    if ($options['cookie_file']){
        if (preg_match("/Set\-Cookie\: /i","$header")){
            $cookie = @explode("Set-Cookie: ",$header,2);
            $cookie = $cookie[1];
            $cookie = explode("\r",$cookie);
            $cookie = $cookie[0];
            $cookie = str_replace("path=/","",$cookie[0]);
            $add = @fopen($options['cookie_file'],'a');
            fwrite($add,$cookie,strlen($read));
            fclose($add);
        }
    }
    if ($_NOT_CURL_GET_OLDHEADER){
        $header = "$_NOT_CURL_GET_OLDHEADER<br /><br />\n$header";
    }
    if ($return[1]){
        $body = $return[1];
    }else{
        $body = "";
    }
    if ($options['return_response_part'] === 'body'){
        $return = $body;
    }
    if ($options['return_response_part'] === 'head'){
        $return = $header;
    }
    if ($options['return_response_part'] === 'all'){
        $return = "$header$body";
    }
    if ($options['follow_location']){
        if (preg_match("/Location\:/","$header")){
            $url = @explode("Location: ",$header);
            $url = $url[1];
            $url = @explode("\r",$url);
            $url = $url[0];
            $_NOT_CURL_GET_OLDHEADER = str_replace("\r\n\r\n","",$header);
            $l = "&#76&#111&#99&#97&#116&#105&#111&#110&#58";
            $_NOT_CURL_GET_OLDHEADER = str_replace("Location:",$l,$_NOT_CURL_GET_OLDHEADER);
            return not_curl_get($url, $protocol, $port, $options);
        }else{
            return $return;
        }
    }else{
        return $return;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for your effort, bu this way does not return me the content of the page, it responses like HTTP Req. ok etc. I actually need exactly the functionality of file_get_contents I think.. Are you sure what exactly this returns? because a possibility about my host has again some permission problems.. by the way this script has a infite loop problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening in your environment, the function does seem to work for me (see this [demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/GPQKF8)). The only posibility for infinite looping should be when the server always sends `location` headers, but you can disable this with the options array.

Comment: u're great bro, thanks a lot, I'll try to solve issues on my host account. Thanks for all your effort. ALl best..